# What kind of plant did EVE find?

Tags: wall-e

In [WALL•E](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/?ref_=nv_sr_4), EVE found a plant when visiting Earth for a routine check.  When reading [this question about the plant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122356/was-the-pea-plant-the-first-plant-found-in-wall-e), it is called a pea plant.  However, it does not actually look much like a pea plant, and it got me to thinking.

What kind of plant is it that is found by EVE?

Comment: An animated plant...I assume the animators don't really care if it looks like a pea plant, though maybe they think pea plants will look different in the future

Comment: When I saw "EVE" I thought of the bible, and then noticed it's on scifi.stackexchange and couldn't help but chuckle. Needless to say, I was slightly disappointed.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Heh... I saw a Hot Network Question this afternoon, saying "What tribe did Paul belong to?" and I thought, "not tribe, sietch" until I noticed that it wasn't for this site.

Comment: @CHEESE What makes you think there's *any* aspect of visual design that animators (especially at Pixar!) "don't really care" about?

Comment: @KyleStrand True.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### In universe

Within the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html) the plant is simply referred to as ...

> ...a SMALL PLANT

This image from the film's concept art archive states that it is indeed a **pea plant**

[image]

That being said, if the animation at the end of the film is anything to go by, it's actually some kind of mutant *pea sapling* since peas don't usually grow into trees.

[image]

---

### Out of universe

According to '[The Art of WALL•E](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URnkBcv38FY&feature=youtu.be&t=2m27s)' the model for EVE's plotline was in fact Noah's Ark, with EVE acting the part of the dove.

> "At a meeting, somebody said that **EVE should be like the dove in the
>   Noah's Ark story.** We thought "that'll work". We rejiggered the story
>   so her job is to bring that plant back to the ship and signal that
>   it's safe to go back to Earth" - <sub><sup>[Jim Reardon - Head of story/writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Reardon)</sup></sub>

That being the case, the twig was inspired by [Genesis 8:11](http://biblehub.com/genesis/8-11.htm) and would have been an **olive branch**

> And the dove came in to him in the evening; and, lo, in her mouth was
>   an olive leaf pluckt off: so Noah knew that the waters were abated
>   from off the earth.

Comment: "Obviously the Captain is hoping for a fine crop of pizzas" - the only way to quiet the masses!

Comment: I initially was going to argue for some kind of vine seedling (because that's the only thing I could find that it's referred as, online), but your answer showed me this was clearly wrong - thank you. Your script reference also suggests that it was deliberately ambiguous, to the point where I think that is likely to be the correct answer. If it *must* be any specific species, then I think circumstantial evidence supporting it being an apple is highest, but I think ambiguity wins.

Comment: @DewiMorgan - I expect they modeled it on a real plant though. I'm trying to find a "making of" that references the design/concept-art process.

Comment: That *would* be the final nail, fersure! Good hunting!

Comment: Richard, it's **not** an olive tree. They don't look like that tree in the gif you included in your answer, and their saplings don't look like the boot's sapling. (Search for images of both saplings, and you will see.)

Comment: @ANeves - I wouldn't take it literally. Inspiration takes odd turns when it comes to the finished article, not to mention the distinct possibility that the plant is some sort of mutated hyper-fertile ultra-hardy hybrid.

Comment: @Richard That goes both ways: their inspiration could have taken odd turns when taking a story where a *dove* carries an *olive* tree *branch*, to make a *robot* carrying a *sapling* of some sort of *climbing plant*. I don't find it a strong claim to support the "olive" claim with parallelism when the other two main characteristics (branch, dove) were also changed. By Occam's Razor, I believe it is not an olive tree. (`distinct possibility that the plant is some sort of mutated hyper-fertile ultra-hardy hybrid` - yes, well pointed.)

Comment: @ANeves - I merely included it for completeness. My personal belief is that it's some kind of mutant apple tree. The plot synthesis between EVE bringing humanity an apple from Eden is simply too delicious to ignore.

Answer (score 46):

My guess is that it was *intended to be* an apple seedling. I regret, however, I have no strong evidence for this - just lots of suggestive hints.

For a start, the sapling *looks* like a CG apple seedling (but note my edit at the bottom about this):

[image: The Wall•E sapling]
The Wall•E sapling.

[image: A CG Apple sapling]
A CG Apple sapling.

Even the EVE project logo, which I feel is a foreshadowing/echo of the seedling she finds, *looks* like an apple tree logo.

[image: The EVE seedling logo]
The EVE seedling logo.

[image: Apple tree logo]
An apple tree logo.

But also, consider the obvious Adam/Eve symbology here.

What plant *would* EVE find, but the apple tree? Metaphorically, it fits: she finds the tree of knowledge that leads humanity away from the Eden of perfect bliss to the deeper life of hardship and knowledge.

But perhaps most significantly, I think, there's another angle. EVE was a love letter to Apple, the company.

Andrew Stanton, Wall•E's director, said "The more I started describing [EVE's design], the more I realized I was pretty much describing the Apple playbook for design." So he called up Steve Jobs, who sent his lead designer, Jonathan Ive, designer of the iMac, iPhone, iPod etc, over to Pixar to consult with Stanton on the prototype. http://www.firstshowing.net/2008/apples-designer-actually-helped-design-wall-es-eve-robot/

Pixar used to be owned by Steve Jobs, until Disney bought it.

The movie features a video iPod (Wall•E watches "Hello Dolly!" on it; the Mac Welcome chime (when Wall•E finishes recharging); Apple mice skitter across the floor; there's a Mac keyboard in Wall•E's truck; the spaceship's computer control speaks with the voice of the early Mac speech synth, "MacinTalk"; and so forth.

Did EVE definitively find an apple? I don't think so. But I don't think any other plant makes sense.

[Edit: all the above said, my impression from the movie was that it was some kind of vine - or a beanstalk? A jack-and-the-beanstalk reference, perhaps? @Valorum makes a good point in their answer that this is provably false given the final credits animation shows it to be a tree sapling, and I think also makes a good, script-referenced argument that the plant is deliberately ambiguous. Oh, and the concept art links of a "pea plant" is essentially identical in shape and even angle to the sapling in Wall•E's hands in the screen shot I link to, so I'd argue that is what it was *designed as*, even if not what it was *intended to be*.]

Comment: The screen-shot from the movie is indeed *very* pea (or other herbaceous legume) looking.

Comment: I love the EVE/apple/Apple connection. Coolness.

Comment: @user23715 Agreed. Trees tend to grow up, fast and straight, to reach light. Legumes tend to wiggle about, to reach support. It was growing wiggly, so suggested a vine.

Comment: The logo on the front of EVE is standardised and doesn't reflect the plant she's found. It's also seen on the front of the '[Operate Manuel](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/File:WALL-E_Operationmanual1.jpg)'

Comment: @Richard Good call: while I personally feel the icon is obviously a deliberate echo (foreshadow?) of the plant she finds, I obviously have no evidence for that *at all*. It just... makes sense? But you're right that I should make this clear for those that have not seen the movie - editing, and thanks :)

Comment: How is it an "apple tree logo"?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it's just a "generic" plant, used by the animators to symbolize the natural world.

That said, I count at least three distinct leaf types in the concept art drawing, each coming from a different type of plant, so it might be a hybrid that was genetically engineered to produce multiple products on the same stem (strawberries on this branch, raspberries on that one, etc.).

The bottom leaf looks like a type of Ground Ivy, which is fairly common where I live. I don't know the others off-hand, but this chart should help identify them.

[image]

Hope this helps!